# Telegram: add callback data to reply_markup

Tags: php, api, telegram

I am trying to add callback data to `reply_markup`.

This is my code:

```
$option[] = array("test");
$replyMarkup = array('keyboard'=>$option,'one_time_keyboard'=>false,'resize_keyboard'=>true,'selective'=>true);
$encodedMarkup = json_encode($replyMarkup,true);
```

This code sends `TEST` to `button` and a call back to server TEST string for case

But I want use TEST string to show user and call back to server by KEY

This code does not work for me:

```
$option[] = array("text"=>"test","call_back"=>"key");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks you try to use [ReplyKeyboardMarkup](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#replykeyboardmarkup). It defines a keyboard with templates of messages which an user can send by tapping on a button.

But you want to get specific key so take a look at [InlineKeyboardMarkup](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinekeyboardmarkup) for this.

```
$options[][] = array('text' => 'Your text', 'callback_data' => 'test-data');
$replyMarkup = array('inline_keyboard' => $options);
$encodedMarkup = json_encode($replyMarkup, true);
```

When an user presses the button, your bot will receive a special update, [CallbackQuery](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#callbackquery).

Comment: Thank you, but inline_keyboard not in bottom button. this reply send as post

Comment: Well, but if you use ReplyKeyboardMarkup, your bot will always receive the same text that is displayed on the button.